# Finding the values of x for which this series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, conditional-convergence

The questions asks...

$$\textrm{For what values of }x \textrm{ do the following series converge, where }a > 0,\,
b > 0?$$

I have managed to find the correct values of $x$ for the first two parts, but the final series is stumping me. The series is...

$$\sum\frac{x^n}{a^n+b^n} \textrm{, which becomes } \frac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}x\,\,\textrm{ after doing the ratio test}$$

I understand that if the fraction tends to $0$ then it works for all values of $x$, but I'm not sure how to *prove* anything beyond this point.

Comment: Where is $c$ used?

Comment: @EuxhenH In a different part of the question, I should probably remove that to avoid further confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}=\frac1{\max\{a,b\}}.$$

Comment: Is that to say if if $a>b, \, \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{a^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a}$ and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So the series converges for $|x|<\textrm{max{a.b}}$?

Comment: Since $|x|=\textrm{max{a.b}}$ would result in a limit of 1 and a divergent series as a result?

Comment: Yes, in both cases.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you: in order to get $\max$, just type `\max` instead of `\textrm{max}`.